# Basic Combinatorics and Counting

Tags: combinatorics

I'm thinking that the number of ways to seat 5 people in 8 chairs is the same as the number of ways to seat 8 people in 5 chairs.

For 5 people in 8 chairs: ${8\choose{5}}5!$ ways.

- Choose the 5 seats that will be used.... $8\choose 5$ ways.
- Scramble the 5 people amongst the chairs selected.... $5!$ ways.

For 8 people in 5 chairs: ${8\choose{5}}5!$ ways.

- Choose the 5 people that will sit in the 5 chairs.... $8\choose 5$ ways.
- Scramble the 5 people amongst the chairs.... $5!$ ways.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: If you seat 8 people in 5 chairs, are the other three sitting in laps?  That will add possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically assigning 5 X to 8 Y. Regardless of whether X and Y are chairs and people, or people and chairs, the math is the same. Such a beautifully universal language!